# Once cable is unplugged, network never restarts, even once plugged back in

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, 19.10, docking

I am running 19.10 on Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme.  I have a docking station that has an ethernet port.  Everything, including etherenet-powered internet connectivity, works fine on initial boot.

However, once I undock, and re-dock, the ethernet connection never reconnects.  My second monitor and other peripherals are fine, but the "Networking" settings show "Network cable is unplugged." It is clearly not unplugged!

The following do nothing to re-establish an ethernet connection:

```
sudo service network-manager restart

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

The only thing that gets me an ethernet connection back is completely rebooting---even logging out of the user and logging back in is insufficient.

This makes a docking station less than perfectly useful.  Shouldn't my machine figure this out automatically just as it does with my monitors?

What information can I provide to make this a fixable report?

Answer (score 1):

Check that the link had carrier (cable plugged in). See the output of `ip link` for that. Especially the `LOWER_UP` flag.

If that is not the case, then either you have a hardware (cable, NIC), firmware or kernel issue. Possibly unloading and reloading the driver would work around the issue (`lsmod`, `rmmod` and `modprobe`). Check whether your kernel driver has reported issues in this regard.

If kernel doesn't say that the interface is connected, NetworkManager cannot do anything about that. And restarting the daemon is almost always the wrong thing to do. But in this case it's useful to confirm that it is probably not a NetworkManager issue.